# I had my image store in document directory.Now i want to know how to display that images and its name on UI Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here I had taken that image document directory and store in array.

But giving some problem in that for part so any help me.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    _arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSError *error = nil;


    NSString *stringPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    //NSLog(@"%@",stringPath);

     _filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath: stringPath  error:&error];

    //NSLog(@"%@",_filePathsArray);

    for(int i=0;i<[_filePathsArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *strFilePath = [_filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i];

       // NSLog(@"%@",strFilePath);

        if ([[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"] || [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"PNG"] || [[strFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"JPG"])
        {
            NSString *imagePath = [[stringPath stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:strFilePath];

            NSLog(@"%@",imagePath);

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];


            //NSLog(@"%@",data);

            if(data)
            {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                NSLog(@"%@",image);

                [_arrayOfImages addObject:image];
                //NSLog(@"%@",_arrayOfImages);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You posted code that looks like it is supposed to build an array of images. Does that code work? If not, what goes wrong? And once you have an array of images, do you know what to do next in order to display the images in a table view? Try writing code to display a table view, and if you have problems, post your code, explain what's wrong, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Hey @DuncanC Sir  In that 1st  _arrayOfImages this output is displaying "2015-11-26 15:53:20.157 exactionsheet[3925:243987] (
)" and In 2nd  _arrayOfImages this output is displaying "2015-11-26 15:53:20.164 exactionsheet[3925:243987] (
"<UIImage: 0x7a0f16d0>, {640, 426}"
)
2015-11-26 15:53:20.165 exactionsheet[3925:243987] (
"<UIImage: 0x7a0f16d0>, {640, 426}",
"<UIImage: 0x797faf90>, {638, 640}"
)
2015-11-26 15:53:20.167 exactionsheet[3925:243987] (
"<UIImage: 0x7a0f16d0>, {640, 426}",
"<UIImage: 0x797faf90>, {638, 640}",
"<UIImage: 0x797ec270>, {640, 426}"
) as i added 3 images

Comment: What do you mean by 1st _arrayOfImages, 2nd _arrayOfImages? And note that you made no attempt to answer the questions I asked about what you are trying to do. Go back and read my comment and edit your question to provide a complete descriptions of what you are asking.